# WHY IS MY BIG QUERY TAB key not indenting my script like it did YESTERDAY? It is now tabbing to the next menu item on the screen?

Tags: google-bigquery

I used to format my sql code by selecting lines and tabbing to indent .
Now tab scrolls through all the menu items on the screen.

I don't think I changed any settings. I don't like the format sql in big query and usally do it manually. But I don't want to have to indent a whole block one line at a time with spaces.

Comment: Are you still experiencing this ? Can you try restarting your browser (or try using incognito for troubleshooting)  with this, I was able to add indention using space or tab I used command Palette -> Convert Indention to space